# How to use the new zoterordfxml feature of Biber?

Tags: biblatex, biber, zotero

I use `zotero` to manage my bibliography and `Biblatex` + `biber` to use it.

For now, I export a .bib file and use it with `Emacs+AUCTex`. I can cite in a very easy way by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>[</kbd> (`AUCTex` cite feature with Regex) and writing the name of the author I want to cited. I can choose, then, the article I want to cite. I automatized the .bib export at each change with [autozotbib plugin](http://www.rtwilson.com/academic/autozotbib).

*But*, it is not perfect : I have some problems with Biblatex fields (zotero seems to export using the Bibtex fields and not biblatex ones). And, I am not refused a way to interconnect more closely zotero and Biblatex (than the simple .bib export).

I read in [biber project page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex-biber/) :

> Experimental support for RIS, Endnote XML and Zotero RDF/XML

When surfing on the web, you can found mention of zoterordrdfxml feature of biber (there is a [man page for ubuntu](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/en/man3/Biber%3a%3aInput%3a%3afile%3a%3azoterordfxml.3pm.html) and a [google groups thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/zotero-dev/DIMpqFZ0vtc)). The biber manual says only :

> Other datasource types : For datasources other than BTEX, (e.g. ris,
>   endnotexml and zoterordfxml), the source entrytypes and fields are
>   usually very differently modelled and named. For example, here is how
>   to drop dc:subject fields from various entrytypes in Zotero XML RDF
>   format data sources:

```
<maps datatype="zoterordfxml" map_overwrite="1">
<map>
<per_type>journalArticle</per_type>
<per_type>book</per_type>
<per_type>bookSection</per_type>
<map_step map_field_set="dc:subject" map_null="1"/>
</map>
</maps>
```

These informations are not sufficient (for me) to use the zoterordfxml (experimental) feature.

**Does someone set successfully Biber to use a zotero database without exporting a .bib file ? (by the help of zoterordfxml feature or not)**

Answer (score 4):

While not a direct answer to your question, note that Zotero now (since about a month) has a dedicated BibLaTex export translator in addition to regular bibtex export  that you can use for better results with biblatex. 
Alternatively, you can also look at the - very similar - biblatex translator here: https://github.com/andersjohansson/zotero-biblatex-translator , which provides some additional functionality based on hacks that aren't officially supported in Zotero. You can configure autozotbib to work with either of these translators - I doubt that anything biber can do with Zotero's RDF export is better than what these translators provide.

Comment: Thks. Do you know how to install/activate the new dedicated BibLaTex export translator? Is it a plugin or embedded in core zotero? I can't find it.

Comment: the built in BibLaTex translator should just be available when you use right-click --> Export selected items

Comment: The "with hacks" version has installation instructions: https://github.com/andersjohansson/zotero-biblatex-translator#installation . AutZotBib tells you how to use alternate Bibtex tranlators under "Advanced Usage" - you can find the IDs of the official BibLaTex translator here: https://github.com/zotero/translators/blob/master/BibLaTeX.js#L2 and the "with hacks" version here: https://github.com/andersjohansson/zotero-biblatex-translator/blob/master/BibLaTeX-with-hacks.js#L2

Comment: I will probably deprecate the zoterordf biber driver - it's always been fairly messy.